# How to filter hidden files after calling MATLAB's dir function

Tags: matlab, filesystems, hidden-files

Using MATLAB, I need to extract an array of "valid" files from a directory.  By valid, I mean they must not be a directory and they must not be a hidden file.  Filtering out directories is easy enough because the structure that `dir` returns has a field called isDir.  However I also need to filter out hidden files that MacOSX *or* Windows might put in the directory.  What is the easiest *cross-platform* way to do this?  I don't really understand how hidden files work.

Comment: No Matlab expert, but this is how hidden files work: on Mac OS X (and other Unix systems), their name starts with a period (`.`). On Windows, their "hidden" attribute is set. Windows hidden files are only hidden on a Windows filesystem, i.e. FAT or NTFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) and [FILEATTRIB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileattrib.html) to check for hidden files.

```
folder = uigetdir('please choose directory');
fileList = dir(folder);

%# remove all folders
isBadFile = cat(1,fileList.isdir); %# all directories are bad

%# loop to identify hidden files 
for iFile = find(~isBadFile)' %'# loop only non-dirs
   %# on OSX, hidden files start with a dot
   isBadFile(iFile) = strcmp(fileList(iFile).name(1),'.');
   if ~isBadFile(iFile) && ispc
   %# check for hidden Windows files - only works on Windows
   [~,stats] = fileattrib(fullfile(folder,fileList(iFile).name));
   if stats.hidden
      isBadFile(iFile) = true;
   end
   end
end

%# remove bad files
fileList(isBadFile) = [];
```

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks for the fix. Ah, copy-paste-forget, bane of my existence!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the `[~,out] = something()` syntax legal on some later version than I'm using?  I usually call `~` as `trash` - but it still makes the assignment.

Comment: @John Berryman: Yes, this has been legal since 2008x, if I recall correctly. The `~` assigns the output to nothing.

Comment: The first two entries might not be . and .. - for instance if you have an Emacs temporary file starting with a # that will come first.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming all hidden files start with '.'. Here is a shortcut to remove them:

```
s = dir(target); % 'target' is the investigated directory

%remove hidden files
s = s(arrayfun(@(x) ~strcmp(x.name(1),'.'),s))
```