# dir()/find() filter out hidden files

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a script that looks at a given directory and grabs all the files for processing.
The issue is that I'd like it to ignore any hidden (.) files.  I saw a number of ways to do this in other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234341/how-to-filter-hidden-files-after-calling-matlabs-dir-function) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/258220), but my case is so simple, I thought it was worth asking as I'm new to octave.  Worth mentioning that the 2nd link is simple, but seems strange that I would have to use a for loop to filter...

Here's my code:

```
dirname = strcat(pwd, '/fileset');
files = dir(dirname);
fileidx = find(~[files.isdir]);

for i = 1:length(fileidx)
    filename = [dirname, '/', files(fileidx(i)).name];
    fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had promised "some more love" for that first line... "the one that didn't work".  Here it is.

There are some interesting ways to manipulate cell arrays that I didn't know until I researched this answer a bit more... In particular, the use of `cellfun()`. I am going to share what I learned.

For example, when you have a cell array of filenames

```
fnames = {files.name};
```

you can apply a regex to find files that match a certain criterion (e.g. "doesn't start with a dot")

```
crit = '^[^.]+';

% return cell array of results, [] if no match
rxResult = regexp( fnames, crit ); 

% loop over all cells, set true if regex matched
nodot = (cellfun('isempty', rxResult)==0); 

% The `nodot` array is a logical array telling us which are "good" files. 
totalGoodFiles = sum(nodot);
```

Now you can use

```
fileidx = find(~[files.isdir] & nodot);
```

On the other hand, you are using a `for` loop already, so you could put your test in there (edited to include file count):

```
fCount=0;
for i = 1:length(fileidx)
if( files(fileidx(i)).name(1) ~= '.')
      filename = [dirname, '/', files(fileidx(i)).name];
      fCount = fCount+ 1;
      fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
    end
end
```

As an aside, there is the function [`fullfile()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) which you can use to concatenate directories and file names; it understands the correct file separator to use for your operating system. Quite handy - better than concatenating '/'. When you try to run on a Mac it will fail...

A further aside - the built in constant `filesep` will return the correct file path separator to use on your platform; good for making your code portable.

Comment: I tried it in the for loop and it seems to work.  The first portion of your answer might need some love, though.

Comment: The concatenation works on Mac.  I'm using octave though, so IDK if that matters.

Comment: Glad you are out of your bind... surprised that the Mac isn't barfing at the '/' (although that's the file separator it uses at the kernel level, it likes ":" at the higher level. Who knows what it's thinking...) I will figure out the "love" for the first line when I'm back at work.

Comment: Yeah, I think I need the first bit actually.  I'm counting the files as I go along and any hidden files being counted in that for loop are going to be misleading to users.